# Understanding .Net Framework 4.5.2+ End of Service

Tags: .net

I'm trying to work out the end of service dates for .Net Framework versions from 4.5.2.

According to the [.Net Framework Support Policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-framework),

> Beginning with version 4.5.2 and later, .NET Framework is defined as a
> component of the Windows operating system (OS). Components receive the
> same support as their parent products, therefore, .NET Framework 4.5.2
> and later follows the lifecycle policy of the underlying Windows OS on
> which it is installed. The support lifecycle for various versions of
> Windows can be found on the Windows lifecycle fact sheet.

We can find which version of Windows different versions of the .Net framework came installed on/are compatible with in [.Net Framework versions and dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies).  This says for example that .Net Framework 4.6:

- Came installed by default on Windows 10
- Is compatible with Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, etc.

There are a couple of aspects of that which aren't clear to me, specifically:

1. Is the .Net Framework support tied to the Windows version it came **installed with by default**, or all of the versions it's **compatible with**?
2. If it's the Windows version it came installed with by default, what does that mean for .Net Framework 4.5.2, which didn't come installed with any?
3. How does this work with .Net Framework versions which came installed on/are compatible with a non-specific Windows 10 version (where end of service is specific to a version)?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't target .NET 4.7.2 already? That's the important question. Sure, 4.5.2 will be supported for quite some time, but that only includes patching.  What about TLS1.2 and TLS1.3 support? It's only supported automatically since 4.6. On top of that, NuGet package authors already require .NET Standard 2.0 at minimum, which means you need 4.7.2

Comment: This is for work - we have lots of software written over many years, and only a small proportion is being actively worked on at any time.  I need to make sure we upgrade anything on older framework versions before they go out of service.

Comment: In that case, you're late already for other reasons. All major services (cloud, Google, banks, payment gateways) stopped supporting TLS1.1 5 years ago. The people that procrastinated fearing "incompatibilities" suddenly had to upgrade  in a couple of months or be unable to do business. On top of that, all .NET 4.x versions are binary replacements so your applications may already be running on newer runtimes simply because the included runtime was upgraded by another application or a Windows Update

Comment: Windows 10, the only supported version, comes with 4.6 *at least*, so you *already* run on 4.6, unless you support customers with unsupported OS versions. Newer Windows 10 versions [come with newer .NET runtimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies), and the service nature of the OS means all installations are getting updated to the latest stable Windows 10 version sooner or later. Windows 10 May 2019 update comes with .NET Framework 4.8

Comment: Windows Server is a different matter, as the OS isn't upgraded automatically. The docs show 4.7.1 was first included 2 years ago.It's a lot easier to update a few servers as needed though,  than dozens or hundreds of desktops.

Comment: In our case it's all Windows Server.